# How can I read the client's machine name from the browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I read the client's machine name from the browser?
Is it possible using JavaScript or angularJS?

Comment: You can't read the client's machine name

Comment: I think its not possible because browser is sandbox environment which means you have a very restrictive access to the underlying machine.

Comment: I donot know why is this duplicate. Here the person is explicitly asking for angular JS not ASP.NET. I have same question in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using JavaScript. If it were possible, that would be a major security risk.

It is however possible from the server. The server can send the data to the client.

Another solution is to use an ActiveX plugin.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1490314.aspx?how+do+get+Client+Machnine+Name+through+Javascript